# Dojo data-dojo-props style overwritten

Tags: css, openlayers, dojo, styling

I'm using a dojo ContentPane to render an openlayers map. When the DOM is ready and the map is inserted the sytle of the dijit is overwritten. I've tried specifiying the height and width in a CSS by class and id, and also inline in my html.

My html:

```
<div id="map-id"
class="centerPanel"
    data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
    data-dojo-props="region: 'center', style: 'width: 1468px;'">
</div>
```

my CSS:

```
#map-id {
width: 1468px;
height: 471px;
}
.centerPanel {
width: 1468px;
height: 471px;
}
```

my actual html from firebug:

```
<div id="map-id" class="centerPanel dijitContentPane dijitBorderContainer-child dijitBorderContainer-dijitContentPane dijitBorderContainerPane dijitAlignCenter olMap" data-dojo-props="region: 'center', style: 'width: 1468px;'" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="" role="group" dir="ltr" style="width: 1455px; left: 252px; top: 48px; right: auto; bottom: auto; height: 456px;" widgetid="map-id">
```

As you can see my data-dojo-props styling is ignorded and the new height and width are inserted...any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like your ContentPane is inside a BorderContainer, in which case it is highly likely that the parent layout widget (the BorderContainer) is dictating the size of the child ContentPane.  Perhaps providing a more complete example of what you want to do would give us more to work with to help.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this in dojo grid and it also does not work. I suggest that you try doing it on javascript code.

add a style object with width and height attribute in the container object instead.

```
myGrid = new DataGrid({
    store: myObjectStore,
    structure : myStructure,
    style: {
        width: '1000px', 
        height: '500px', 
    },
}, "myGrid");
```

I believe that the declarative way does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a `doLayout:false` on your container, if any :)

Answer (score 0):

The center region of a BorderContainer gets sized to fill up any remaining space available. If you want your center region to be a particular size then you need to style the BorderContainer rather than the widget that occupies the center region.